# Magento Contact Form missing

Tags: forms, magento, contacts, magento-1.8

really strange my contact us is missing in the footer and on the navigation bar

i have custom theme and it was before working but not anymore .
here is the message it giving me when i go by the link .

Fatal error: Call to a member function setFormAction() on a non-object in /mounted-storage/home159/sub018/sc85272-SRLF/caramellachocolates.com/ccd/app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php on line 55

ive also copied the contacts folder from the default theme and pasted in custom i also copied the xml file from default and pasted in custom . but still getting this error.

Comment: Are you able to share the contents of that file. More specifically what is around line 55?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello add below code into indexcontroller.php may be help you

```
require_once 'Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php';
class MyNameSpace_Yourmodule_Contacts_IndexController extends Mage_Contacts_IndexController
{
//do somthing
}
```